# How to structure Java Code keeping Packages in mind

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Consider a scenario of

a jar with 10 packages which is to be used by our client

A class in a package that is to be used by the end user has to declare some fields which is to be used internally among packages but it's not to be made visible to client

How would you hide it because otherwise we have to provided Java-docs for it and it is of internal use only

.Net provides the access modifier 'internal' to overcome this but this is missing in java.

How to avoid such problems or what is the correct way of notifying the end user ?

Comment: Would that SO question on [javadoc usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779781/javadoc-subsets-java-library-organization) help you ?

Comment: Use "default" access modifier which is also known as “package-level” access.

Comment: i want to access between properties and i dont want to use java docs since thats just documentation, the core problem is that api is exposed to users whereas it should've not been